# Get the value of TextField in a custom created Widget in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have created a custom Widget in flutter that contains a Text and a TextField in a Column.
The problem is that I don't know how I can get the value of TextField when I use this widget in my app .

here is the the widget I've created :

```
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget{
  String ?value;
  String ?text;
  String ?hint;

  CustomTextField({this.text, this.hint});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text("$text", style:
            TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.deepPurple[500]
            ),),
          ),
          TextField(
            onSubmitted: (String value) {
              if (value.isNotEmpty){
                this.value = value;
              }
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "$hint",
                focusedBorder : OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple.shade200,
                        width: 4.0
                    )
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        width: 2.0
                    )
                )
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is how I use it :

```
class _CreateItemState extends State<CreateItem> {

  String ?todoTitle;
  String ?todoDesc;
  bool todoIsDone = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[300],
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Create TODO Items"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomTextField(
              text: "Title: ",
              hint: "Write a title here ...",
            ),
            CustomTextField(
              text: "Description: ",
              hint: "Write a description here ...",
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Submit",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple[500],
                    fontSize: 20
                ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know how I can get the value for every field that I create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
class _CreateItemState extends State<CreateItem> {
  String ?todoTitle;
  String ?todoDesc;
  bool todoIsDone = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[300],
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Create TODO Items"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomTextField(
              text: "Title: ",
              hint: "Write a title here ...",
              onSubmit: (value){
                //here is the value for this widget with textfield
              },
            ),
            CustomTextField(
              text: "Description: ",
              hint: "Write a description here ...",
              onSubmit: (value){
                //here is the value for this widget with textfield
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Submit",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.deepPurple[500],
                      fontSize: 20
                  ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget{
  String ?text;
  String ?hint;
  Function(String) onSubmit;

  CustomTextField({this.text, this.hint,required this.onSubmit});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text("$text", style:
            TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.deepPurple[500]
            ),),
          ),
          TextField(
            onSubmitted: this.onSubmit,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "$hint",
                focusedBorder : OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple.shade200,
                        width: 4.0
                    )
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        width: 2.0
                    )
                )
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ritik kumar srivastava ! it worked well !